# Backbone+Parse.com Collection.fetch() returns empty array using event callback

Tags: backbone.js, parse-platform, backbone-boilerplate

i'm starting using parse.com to develop a web app but i'm stuck on a simple problem.
I defined a model (or object in Parse SDK) as:

```
Book.Model = Parse.Object.extend("book", {
    // Default attributes for the book.
    defaults: {
      title: "placeholder...",
    },

    // Ensure that each book created has `title`.
    initialize: function() {
      if (!this.get("title")) {
        this.set({"title": this.defaults.title});
      }
    },

  });
```

and a collection:

```
Book.List = Parse.Collection.extend({

    // Reference to this collection's model.
    model: Book.Model,

    initialize: function() {
    },

  });
```

Then, if i try something like

```
   var books = new Book.List();
   books.fetch({
        success: function(collection) {
            console.warn(collection);
        },
        error: function(collection, error) {
           // The collection could not be retrieved.
        }
    });
```

Everything goes fine. Log:

```
child {length: 5, models: Array[5], _byId: Object, _byCid: Object, model: function…}
_byCid: Object
_byId: Object
length: 5
models: Array[5]
__proto__: EmptyConstructor
```

BUT if i try to use event callback instead of success method i get an empty array. Code:

```
books.on('reset', this.log());
books.fetch();

    log: function() {
      console.log(books);
    }
```

and log:

```
child {length: 0, models: Array[0], _byId: Object, _byCid: Object, model: function…}
_byCid: Object
_byId: Object
length: 5
models: Array[5]
__proto__: EmptyConstructor
```

which is quite strange (because i think that each solution wait for the collection to be populated from the server). Does anybody know why is this happening?

I'm actually using Backbone Boilerplate and Parse.com js SDK.

Comment: obviously i know it's not an empty object but if i use the toJSON() method it actually returns empty array. Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Collection#fetch`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch) behavior has changed, it used to reset the collection by default but as of [1.0.0 it merges the new models](http://backbonejs.org/#changelog) using `set`:

> When the model data returns from the server, it uses *set* to (intelligently) merge the fetched models, unless you pass `{reset: true}`, [...]

and [`set`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-set) doesn't trigger `"reset"` events, it triggers other events:

> All of the appropriate `"add"`, `"remove"`, and `"change"` events are fired as this happens.

If you want your `fetch` to reset the collection then you have to say so:

```
books.fetch({ reset: true });
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but this is not the point for two reasons: i'm on backbone 0.9.2 and fetch method actually fires a 'reset' event (otherwise it wouldn't log anything).
Just to be sure i tried your way (both fetch({reset:true}) and add,remove,change event binding) but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @user1203806: Are you really doing `books.on('reset', this.log());` rather than `books.on('reset', this.log);`? You're not supposed to call the method when binding to an event, you're supposed to pass the method itself.

Comment: oh god, i feel so stupid... thank you! 
So, if i do this.log() the log method is evaluated just after the binding itself get evaluated, instead if i do this.log it wait for the reset event to be fired, did i understand? i tried to search on stackoverflow, but i don't know what keywords to use.

Comment: If you do `books.on('reset', this.log())` then `log` is called *before* `books.on` is called, `log` is called while building the argument list for the `books.on` call; if you `books.on('reset', this.log)` then `log` is called when the `'reset'` happens. Don't feel too bad, I didn't spot that either.