# Backbone Collection return wrong data

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

Hi i have backbone app as follows:

code.js.coffee

```
window.Code =
  Models: {}
  Collections: {}
  Views: {}
  Routers: {}
  initialize: ->
   new Code.Routers.Todos();
   Backbone.history.start()

$(document).ready ->
  Code.initialize()
```

todos_router.js.coffee

```
class Code.Routers.Todos extends Backbone.Router
    routes:
        '': 'index'
        'todos/:id': 'show'

    initialize: ->
        @collection = new Code.Collections.Todos()
        @collection.fetch()
    index: ->
        view = new Code.Views.TodosIndex(collection: @collection)
        view.render()
        $('#container').html(view.el)

    show: (id)->
        alert "#{id}"
```

todos.js.coffee --> collection

```
class Code.Collections.Todos extends Backbone.Collection
  url: '/todos'
```

todos_index.js.coffee

```
class Code.Views.TodosIndex extends Backbone.View

  template: JST['todos/index']

  initialize: -> 


      this.collection.on('reset',this.render,this)

  render: ->
      $(@el).html(@template(todo: this.collection))
```

Now the issues is when i render  collection on template to get length, it still giving me result 0 even though there is 1 records on database. What am i done wrong here? The console outputs of this.collection are as follow

```
Todos {length: 0, models: Array[0], _byId: Object, constructor: function, url: "/todos"…}
_byId: Object
_events: Object
length: 1
models: Array[1]
__proto__: ctor
```

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of Backbone are you using?

Comment: @muistooshort on my gem file i just add gem 'backbone-on-rails'

Comment: And which version of Backbone is that using? Does your `render` get called once or twice?

Comment: @muistooshort how can i call the latest backbone-on-rails version?

Comment: Try looking at `Backbone.VERSION` in the JavaScript console. And throw a quick `console.log('render called')` in your `render` to see how many times it gets called.

Comment: @muistooshort it's version 1.0.0

Comment: `Collection#fetch`'s behavior changed in 1.0.0: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16245753/479863

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had some trouble getting the `reset` event to fire on a collection fetch. Are you interested specifically in the collection being *reset* or are you just interested when the fetch has completed the operation of retrieving data from the API? If the latter, try this code in your view:

**todos_index.js.coffee**

```
class Code.Views.TodosIndex extends Backbone.View
  template: JST['todos/index']

  initialize: -> 
    @collection.on 'sync', @render

  render: =>
      $(@el).html(@template(todo: @collection))
```

See [the list of exposed events](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog) for more information on when each event fires. Also note that the `fetch` method [takes a variety of boolean flags](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch) that specify if certain events are fired.

If you really need to hook into the `reset` event (that is, you want to know when the collection has been *emptied* of its contents) then you could try something like this:

**todos_router.js.coffee**

```
class Code.Routers.Todos extends Backbone.Router
    routes:
        '': 'index'
        'todos/:id': 'show'

    initialize: ->
        @collection = new Code.Collections.Todos()
        @collection.fetch
          reset: true
          silent: false

    index: ->
        view = new Code.Views.TodosIndex(collection: @collection)
        view.render()
        $('#container').html(view.el)

    show: (id)->
        alert "#{id}"
```

**todos_index.js.coffee**

```
class Code.Views.TodosIndex extends Backbone.View
  template: JST['todos/index']

  initialize: -> 
    @collection.on 'reset', @render

  render: =>
      $(@el).html(@template(todo: @collection))
```

As a secondary suggestion, you may want to push the @collection down into the view as opposed to keeping it in the router, unless you need to re-use the collection across views.